# Variational lemma - inequality version

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Suppose $f\in L^2(a,b)$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$. How to prove (if it is possible) that

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\varphi(t)dt\ge0\,\forall\varphi\in C^{\infty}_{0}(a,b)\,\text{and}\,\varphi\ge 0\Rightarrow f(t)\ge 0\,\,\text{a.e.}\, t\in(a,b)?$$

Comment: Do you really want $\varphi \geq 0$?

Comment: I mean that for every $t\in (a,b)$, $\varphi(t)\ge 0$.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? What if $f$ is a positive function?

Comment: You are right, the implication should give $f(t)\ge 0$. I think the proof can now be easily derived arguing by contradiction.